# SMTP stress test

Tags: linux, smtp, test

does anyone knows of any good software for Mac OS X or at least for RHEL/CENTOS Linux that I can run against my SMTP Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used Russell Coker's* [postal](http://doc.coker.com.au/projects/postal/) in the past.

*Of bonnie++ fame.

Comment: I'd second that.

Comment: On OS X latest versions of postal give a Bus Error.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try Xstress http://xstress.sourceforge.net/ although you will have to compile it from the source code.

From their Readme:

xstress is an SMTP Stress Testing Tool. Essentially xstress creates multiple connections to (your) mail server and sends multiple mails repeatedly over all connections.